# WiX Installer Bootstrapper - How to set a string variable based on a condition?

Tags: wix, bootstrapper

I am using a Wix bootstrapper.  I have a custom Theme that has a radio button that sets variables called "Client" or "Server", based on which button is selected.

What I'm searching for is a way to have the "InstallCommand" in an "ExePackage" be different based on whether "Client" or "Server" is set.  (They are boolean "1" or "0") variables.

I could always duplicate the "ExePackage" and run the same installer executable with a different InstallCommand based on the variable.  That has worked for me in the past.  However, I am trying to avoid including the ExePackage twice, since it's rather large and would unnecessarily bloat the bootstrapper executable.

I was thinking of trying to set a variable or property based on whether one or the other is set, then use that variable or property in the InstallCommand.  Any thoughts on how to go about doing this?  I've searched and I can't find a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My research has indicated that this simply cannot be done with the Wix managed bootstrapper application.  You have to "roll your own" custom bootstrapper application to achieve this.